# Spring MVC App, in form:input path= converts given object to string, when I need the object to acces a value of the map

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, model-view-controller, path

In my Spring MVC app I'm trying to create a small form, that updates a parameter of a `object (Quantity)`, that is a value in a map, which `keys` are `objects (Case)`.

I get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property
>   'cases[Case o wymiarach: 300x200x100mm i powierzchni 0.22m2,
>   typ=KUFER, material=SKLEJKA, kolor=BLACK, wypelnienie=FOAM,
>   uchwyty=KASETOWY, iloscUchwytow=0, kola=false, iloscKol=0,
>   zamki=MOTYLKOWE, uwagi=, cena=110.0zł]' of bean class
>   [com.wojto.wmcase.entity.Order]: Invalid index in property path
>   'cases[Case o wymiarach: 300x200x100mm i powierzchni 0.22m2,
>   typ=KUFER, material=SKLEJKA, kolor=BLACK, wypelnienie=FOAM,
>   uchwyty=KASETOWY, iloscUchwytow=0, kola=false, iloscKol=0,
>   zamki=MOTYLKOWE, uwagi=, cena=110.0zł]'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'com.wojto.wmcase.entity.Case' for property 'null'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.wojto.wmcase.entity.Case': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

The code fragment looks like this:

```
<form:form action="updateQuantity" modelAttribute="order" method="PUT">
   <form:input class="" path="cases[${tempCase}].quantity" 
        value="${order.getCases().get(tempCase).getQuantity()}"/>
                                |
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link my-3" >Zapisz ilość</button>
 </form:form></td>
```

The **tempCase** gets created like this:

```
<c:forEach var="tempCase" items="${order.getCaseList()}">
```

So, what is happening here is that path receives the proper object (the parameters are as expected), but for some reason is converting in to a String with it's `toString()` method, after which it complains that it can't convert it back from `String` to `Case`...

I've also tried: `cases['${tempCase}']`, `cases['tempcase']`, and `cases[tempCase]`. It always converts it to a String, in the last two it takes literally a "tempCase" String.

The entities:

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy=false)  // test
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="case_quantities",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="quantity_id", 
        referencedColumnName="id")}
        )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="case_id")
    private Map<Case, Quantity> cases;

    @Column(name="comments")
    private String comments;
    @Column(name="charge")
    private double charge;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;
    @Column(name="dt")
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                         CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    private Client client;
(...)
    public Map<Case, Quantity> getCases() {
        if(cases == null) {
            this.cases = new HashMap<Case, Quantity>();
        }
        return cases;
    }

    public List<Case> getCaseList(){
        if(cases == null) {
            this.cases = new HashMap<Case, Quantity>();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(cases.keySet());
    }
(...)
```

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="cases")
public class Case {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="length")
    private int length;
    @Column(name="width")
    private int width;
    @Column(name="height")
    private int height;
    @Column(name="surface")
    private double surface;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Material material;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Color color;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Filling filling;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Handle handle;
    @Column(name="handle_num")
    private int handleNum;

    @Column(name="wheels")
    private boolean wheels;
    @Column(name="wheel_num")
    private int wheelNum;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Locks locks;

    @Column(name="comments")
    private String comments;
    @Column(name="price")
    private double price;

    // Testing a bi-directional relationship
    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    private Order order;
(...)
```

The controller method

```
    @PutMapping("/updateQuantity")
    public String updateQuantity(@RequestParam("quantity") int quantity,
                                 @ModelAttribute("tempCase") Case tempCase,
                                 @ModelAttribute("order") Order theOrder,
                                 Model theModel) {

        theOrder.getCases().get(tempCase).setQuantity(quantity);

        theModel.addAttribute(theOrder);

        return "redirect:/continueOrder";
    }
```

The whole jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!-- The below enabled Polish character rendering -->
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pl">

<head>
    <title>WMCASE - </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />

    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark m-0">
        <h2 class="text-light text-center p-3">WMCase - Prośba o wycenę</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid align-center">

        <form:form action="newCaseInOrder" method="GET">
            <input name="order" type="hidden" value="${order}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj Skrzynkę" class="btn btn-dark my-3" />
        </form:form>

        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="10">Skrzynki</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Wymiary</th>
                    <th scope="col">Typ</th>
                    <th scope="col">Materiał</th>
                    <th scope="col">Kolor</th>
                    <th scope="col">Wypełnienie</th>
                    <th scope="col">Rączki</th>
                    <th scope="col">Koła</th>
                    <th scope="col">Zamki</th>
                    <th scope="col">Uwagi</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ilość</th>
                    <th scope="col">Akcja</th>
                </tr>

            <c:forEach var="tempCase" items="${order.getCaseList()}">

            <!-- Update case, quantity and delete Links -->
            <c:url var="updateQuantityLink" value="/updateQuantity">
                <c:param name="tempCase" value="${tempCase}"/>
                <c:param name="order" value="${order}"/>
            </c:url>

            <c:url var="updateLink" value="/updateCase">
                <c:param name="caseId" value="${tempCase.id}"/>
                <c:param name="orderId" value="${order}" />
            </c:url>

            <c:url var="deleteLink" value="/deleteCase">
                <c:param name="caseId" value="${tempCase.id}"/>
                <c:param name="orderId" value="${order}" />
            </c:url> 

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td> ${tempCase.length} x ${tempCase.width} x ${tempCase.height} mm</td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.type.getType()}</td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.material.getMaterial()}</td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.color.getColor()}</td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.filling.getFilling()}</td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.handle.getHandle()} - ${tempCase.getHandleNum() } </td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.getWheels()} - ${tempCase.getWheelNum()}</td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.locks.getLocks()} </td>
                        <td> ${tempCase.comments}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form:form action="updateQuantity" modelAttribute="order" method="PUT">

                                <form:input class=""
                                            path="cases[${tempCase}].quantity"
                                            value="${order.getCases().get(tempCase).getQuantity()}"/>
                                |
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link my-3" >Zapisz ilość</button>
                            </form:form></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="${updateLink}">Modyfikuj</a>
                             |
                            <a href="${deleteLink}"
                            onclick="if (!(confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć skrzynkę?'))) return false">
                            Usuń</a>
                        <td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <%-- </c:forEach> --%>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>
        <hr>


        <h3 class="">Dane kontaktowe:</h3>
        <form:form action="sendOrder" modelAttribute="order" method="POST">
            <form:hidden path="id"/>

            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-auto form-group row">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Imię:</label>
                    <form:input class="form-control mx-3 text-right" type="text" path="client.name" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto form-group row">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Nazwisko:</label>
                    <form:input class="form-control mx-3 text-right" type="text" path="client.surname" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto form-group row">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Email:</label>
                    <form:input class="form-control mx-3 text-right" type="text" path="client.email" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto form-group row">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Telefon:</label>
                    <form:input class="form-control ml-3 text-right" type="text" path="client.tel" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="col-form-label">Komentarz:</label>
                <form:textarea rows="4" cols="30" class="form-control" type="text" path="comments" />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark my-3" >Wyślij zapytanie</button>

         </form:form>

        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/clientOrders?clientId=${clientId}">Wróć do zamówień</a>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: visual]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add also the code of your model classes and the controller and/or service which implements the logic you're using.

Comment: Hi, I've added the Entities and the Controller method.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The form:input is a simple textfield right? Another question, is correct that you try to index the array cases with an object? I think you should add the whole code of the jsp page to make it clearer. Can you also add the graphical output of the web page, please?

Comment: The form:input is supposed to view, and take an integer.
I am trying to make it possible to change the quantity of a specific user created Case object (like the number of items in a shopping basket). The quantity is a Value in a Map, to whick the keys are Cases (like, the whole object in th backend side).
The <c:forEach> in deed does change objects into Strings under the **var** parameter, and I need the object, not it's string representation to get a Value (Quantity) from the map. Is there a way to convert the String back into an object? Or maybe something instead of <c:forEach> I Can use?

Comment: As a starting point, I would use the id of the `Case` object as key of the map and not the object itself. What's the purpose of `path` attribute?

Comment: I imagine that *Ilosc* is the quantity that you want to modify for the specified Case object, right?

Comment: I could use the Id as the key, but then I would probably have to have another List just to keep the Cases.
The purpose of path is to update the quantity. It should direct to the parameter of the Quantity object that holds the ammount of that specific item. "Zapisz ilość" means "save quantity", so that field is a mini form made only to update the quantity of a specific Case. 
You are correct, "Ilość" means Quantity.
Maybe in forEach instead of iterating just a list of Cases, I should iterate a Map of key-value pairs. But I'm guessing those will be converted to Strings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. The problem was indeed the fact, that in forEach the var attribute is converted to a String, and not converted back to a Case when I try to acces a value in a map with it. So insted of trying to target the edited parameter directly to the Quantity held by the Order I save the new quantity in a temporary Quantity object, that is in the Model, and then use it to update The real quantity object in the Map held by the Order.

**The jsp**

```
(...)
            <c:forEach var="tempCase" items="${order.getCases()}">
(...)
                            <form:form action="updateQuantity" modelAttribute="tempQuantity" method="PUT">
                                <input name="tempCase" type="hidden" value="${tempCase.key}"/>
                                <form:input class=""
                                            path="quantity"
                                            value="${tempCase.value.quantity}"
                                            />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link my-3" > Zapisz ilość</button>
                            </form:form></td>
(...)
```

**The controller**

```
(...)
    @PostMapping("/addCaseToOrder")
    public String addCaseToOrder(@ModelAttribute("case") Case theCase,
                                 @ModelAttribute("order") Order theOrder,
                                 Model theModel) {

        System.out.println("Executing the addCaseToOrderMethod");
        theCase.evaluation();
        theOrder.addCase(theCase);
        theOrder.getCharge();
        System.out.println(theCase.toString());
        theModel.addAttribute("order", theOrder);
        System.out.println(theOrder.getCases().size());

        return "redirect:/continueOrder";
    }

    @GetMapping("/continueOrder")
    public String continueOrder(@ModelAttribute("order") Order theOrder,
                                Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("order", theOrder);

        Quantity tempQuantity = new Quantity();
        theModel.addAttribute("tempQuantity", tempQuantity);

        System.out.println("Executing the continueOrder method");
        System.out.println(theOrder.getCases().size());

        return "new-full-order";
    }
(...)
```

I still had a problem with the fact that my tempCase was a String. So I found a dirty solution. I loop through the Cases held by the Order, convert them to Strings and compare to the tempCase wich already is a String. And when I get a match I use the found Case as a key to update the quantity. :D

**The Controller**

```
(...)
    @PostMapping("/updateQuantity")
    public String updateQuantity(@ModelAttribute("tempQuantity") Quantity tempQuantity,
                                 @ModelAttribute("tempCase") String tempCaseString,
                                 @ModelAttribute("order") Order theOrder,
                                 Model theModel) {

        for (Case checkedCase : theOrder.getCaseList()) {
            if (checkedCase.toString().equals(tempCaseString)) {
                System.out.println("Found equal cases");
                theOrder.getCases().get(checkedCase).setQuantity(tempQuantity.getQuantity());
            }
        }

        theModel.addAttribute(theOrder);

        return "redirect:/continueOrder";
    }
(...)
```

Still got some cleaning up to do.

Thanks for your help A. Wolf!